# Imbrication of a variable number of loop

Tags: python

I have trouble automating a variable number of loop.
I have a tkinter interface, with some checkbox.
There must be as many loops as checked boxes.
For example if 2 boxes are checked my code must be:

```
For i in range(a1,a2):
  For j in range(b1,b2):
```

If 3 boxes are checked:

```
 For i in range(a1,a2):
  For j in range(b1,b2):
   For k in range(c1,c2):
```

So the idea will be:

```
If box1 is checked:
  For i in range(a1,a2):
    If box2 is checked:
      For j in range(b1,b2):
```

But there is to much boxes so to much possibility to write.

Anyone have an idea ? 
Thanks you !

Comment: You could use recursion.

Comment: If this is supposed to be Python, the keywords `for` and `if` have  to be all lower-case.

Comment: Take a look at `itertools.product`

Answer (score 0):

Use `itertools.product`:

```
possible_ranges = [range(a1, a2), range(b1, b2), range(c1, c2)]
for t in itertools.product(*possible_ranges[:num_boxes_checked]):
    ...
```

`t` will be a tuple with `num_boxes_checked` elements.